# Why are callbacks of some functions put in Event queue?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I am new to Javascript and Asynchronous programming, a few things confuse me.

Consider the following code

```js
function fun(callback) {

  console.log('a');

  setTimeout(callback,0);

  console.log('c');
}

fun(() => {console.log('b');});
```

I know that the callback of `setTimeout` function is put inside Event queue and rest are put inside call stack, tasks in event queue are executed only when call stack is empty, but I know that is not the case for all callbacks.
What makes functions like `setTimeout` special ?

If there are any misfacts in my understandings please point it out.

Answer (score 2):

You know almost all, If we use setTimeout example like this : `setTimeout(func, 0)`, This ensures that the func is scheduled as soon as possible. But the timer does this only when the current code operation is finished. Therefore, the timer starts running "right after" the current job. In other words, "asynchronous". For example, the code below prints "Hello" followed by "World".

```
setTimeout(() => alert("World"), 0);
alert("Hello");
```

In the first line it means "queue the call after 0ms".But the timer looks after "check queue first" ie after running the current code.From this "Hello" is written before "World" after.I hope I could explain. Happy coding!!!